# Page Not Found when click on category link?

Tags: category, url, ce-1.9.0.1, products

Unable to get Products when click on category.

Code:

```
<?php
    $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);       

    foreach ($_categories as $_category)
        {  
            if($_category->getImageUrl())  
                {  
                    $catimg     = $_category->getImageUrl();  
?>
<div class="category1">  
<img src="<?php echo $catimg ;?>" alt="" />
  <a class="cate_btn" title="View the products for this category" href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl($_category) ;?>">View</a>
  </div> 

<?php } } ?>
```

when i click on view,it leads to following url:

```
rtd/index.php/catalog/category/view/s/cat1/id/3/
```

This Page gives error Message as Following:

```
Whoops, our bad...

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

        If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
        If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

What can you do?
    Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Store.

        Go back to the previous page.
        Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
        Follow these links to get you back on track!
        Store Home | My Account
```

Help me out guys  ,I'M new To Magento ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answer to my own question.i have done it.i kept my this coding in list.phtml as posted in question:

```
<?php
    $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);       

    foreach ($_categories as $_category)
        {  
            if($_category->getImageUrl())  
                {  
                    $catimg     = $_category->getImageUrl();  
?>
<div class="category1">  
<img src="<?php echo $catimg ;?>" alt="" />
  <a class="cate_btn" title="View the products for this category" href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl($_category) ;?>">View</a>
  </div> 

<?php } } ?>
```

I just drag all categories to default category:like this

[image]

with this url is changed as following.and it worked.

rtd/index.php/cat1.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to do "catalog url rewriting " reindex and clear the cache.

Comment: can you explain your answer ,why and how can we do this in backend in magento.?

Comment: jigesh..I reindex catalog urls and  cleared the cache.but same result.

Comment: <?php $_helper= Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active'); ?>
<?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
</br>
    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category); ?>">
          <?php echo$_category->getName() ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach;?>

Comment: try above code and give me the results.

Comment: catalog/category/view/s/cat1/id/3/ this will not work at all. because the main or default category we can not show on the page. only product listing we can see. if your trying to show the default or main category or with its subcategory than you have to customize the coding.

Comment: Like.
Category1->Sub1,Sub2,Sub3
and when user click on Sub1-> than list of product.
if you want to do this like than tell me i will help you.

Comment: same error is coming with ur code, page not found.and i have all root categories.when i click on any cat,i want to show all products related to this cat.

Comment: ok,why this link is generated automatically with my and your coding  ==>catalog/category/view/s/cat1/id/3/ if this link is wrong.can we change this link??????how

Comment: have you assign the product to categories?

Comment: have you got any link with .html extension? that link will show the products. and for your question why the link is generated i have to research. if you have skype add me jignesh261991 or mail me to jigneshsorathiya2012@gmail.com